# Twilio Library Suddenly Stopped Giving me Call Sid

Tags: java, android, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

i am using twilio android sdk for calling .. it is working fine..
but i am getting a very wierd issue right now

I was using the following code to fetch the call sid as soon as the onConnected method gets fired.. the call is working fine.. but this particular code through which i am getting the call sid has stopped working suddenly ! this was working fine earlier... please help somebody!!

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Connection eer) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected");

       String sid = connection.getParameters()
                        .get(Connection.IncomingParameterCallSIDKey); 
             Log.e("call_sid", sid + "on connected");
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: i am not getting any error in this.. it is returning null value.. it was working perfectly before

Comment: I would raise this issue with Twilio support and they can look into why SIDs aren't available. [Get in touch with them via this form](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and if you can give them any more information about the calls then do provide as much as you can.

Comment: i just found something very interesting @philnash.. the above code is working fine in eclipse.. but the same not working in Android studio.. please fix this issue as soon as possible.. as i checked the latest quickstart code provided by twilio for android..

Comment: That is interesting, thanks for following up. I have reported it, but it would help if you were to raise the issue with our support team too. That way they will see it is a user need and you will receive a response for when it is resolved. The form to get in touch is here: https://www.twilio.com/help/contact

Comment: @philnash i have already filled up the form .. waiting for the reply from twilio.. please tell your twilio team to get this issue resolved as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for that, I hope they can sort it soon for you too.

Comment: @philnash  brother .. i am not getting any reply from twilio

Comment: Vivek, I don't see a help ticket related to this issue. If you have a reference number for it, can you email mspeir@twilio.com?

Comment: @MeganSpeir  i have just mailed you .. please check it asap!